# How to exclude the hovered td from table's hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, blur

I want to apply the filter called "blur" on a table (just on hover in css) excluding the td that has the hover in that moment. Otherwise the filter blur is applied from the page load.
So, how can I exclude a td hovered from a table's hover, only by using CSS?

```
table td {
    filter: blur(1px);
}   

td:hover {
    filter:blur(0px)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So that the table is blurred only when hovered, you have to use the selector `table:hover`. Now, because the filter applied to an element is also applied to its children elements, and because you want one of the cell (which is a child element) not to have that filter, you cannot apply it to the whole table. Instead, you need to apply it to every individual cell inside the hovered table, just like you did but with the added pseudo-selector: `table:hover td`.

Then, to remove the filter from the hovered cell, you would naturally apply the filter to the following selector: `td:hover`. The problem here is that you're already targeting all the table cells with the previous selector (`table:hover td`), and that first selector has a higher specificity (12) than the second one (11). So that the second selector wins, it has to have at least the same specificity and be placed after the first one.

To increase its specificity by 1, you can simply add `table` followed by a space in front of it. It means it targets the hovered cell in the table, which is what you want.

You end up with the following working code:

```css
table:hover td { /* Specificity 12 */
  filter: blur(1px);
}

table td:hover { /* Also specificity 12, but placed after, so it wins */
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Love you! Thanks so much for your clear explanation!

Comment: @JamesMclaren if the answer solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer and give it an upvote, this is a good practice.